# Integrate Firebase with our server to send notification over android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working with android. I need to send notification to selected users from my server, so, I have to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging or Google Cloud Messaging.

What is the exact difference between FCM and GCM except analysis? Can I integrate FCM with my server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FCM is the newest version of GCM.

You can integrate FCM with your own server.
Check this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server).

Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) to set up Android client.

GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM, in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.
So go on with FCM.

Check this too [FCM_vs_GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq) or this talk [GCM is now FCM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VpbNFIY1qJ0&index=19&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlAyGS6_paVoGJ9YKC7J3NN) from Google I/O.

Comment: Hi Jenson, Thanks for helping me. I have developed an android app with firebase sdk but whenever i send notification from Firebase Admin Panel, this app crashes. I don't know what's happening with this app. I have developed this app by going through to [url](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Comment: Can u please post the crash log?

Comment: Yaa Sure. Just give me few minutes.

Comment: Now, i am trying to send notification from admin panel of firebase but nothing is happening. I have done the same work as they mentioned.

Comment: Make sure you have added the service to your manifest. if everything is fine, please cross check with this project.(https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging)

Comment: I have already added 2 services in manifest but i'll try with this link.

Comment: Can you please check my code. I have uploaded it over the github. [Path](https://github.com/jainshravan123/AndroidFirebase/tree/master/AndroidFirebase) It is not working. Nothing is showing when i am sending the notification from FCM Admin Panel.

Comment: Now it is working fine. I forgot to call sendNotification(String) method. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: `{ "notification": {
    "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark",
    "text": "5 to 1"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}`          This is the message format for sending this message to a particular user. What will be the JSON for sending the same message to all of the users?

Comment: I just visited this site , in my case this was very helpful with complete description(even for beginner ).
http://easybook4u.com/index.php/2017/08/25/android-push-notification-in-kotlin-using-fcm/

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google cloud messaging guidelines](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/):

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits
>   the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! If you are integrating messaging in a new app,
>   start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM,
>   in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.

Also [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#messaging-difference) is more details about the difference:

> Firebase Cloud Messaging provides a complete set of messaging
>   capabilities through its client SDKs and HTTP and XMPP server
>   protocols. For deployments with more complex messaging requirements,
>   FCM is the right choice.
>
> Firebase Notifications is a lightweight, serverless messaging solution
>   built on Firebase Cloud Messaging. With a user-friendly graphical
>   console and reduced coding requirements, Firebase Notifications lets
>   users easily send messages to reengage and retain users, foster app
>   growth, and support marketing campaigns.
>
> Here's a comparison of the messaging capabilities provided by Firebase
>   Cloud Messaging and Firebase Notifications:

[image]

Also [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) is the complete reference that guides you how to implement client and server with firebase notification.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I am going through to this tutorial. This is having awesome content. Thanks You.